# ¿Como Deserializo un Archivo .json?

Tags: c#, linq

Estoy haciendo unos ejercicios de LINQ, donde tengo que hacer unas query sobre un **archivo .json**. Necesito que muestre Fabricantes y Modelos que sean del color "Fuscia".

**Formato Json:**

```
{"id":1,"Maker":"Mercedes-Benz","Model":"SL-Class","Year":null,"Color":null,"Location":{"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null}}
```

He creado una clase para poder pasar a un `List<>` este .json, quedando asi:

```
class Cars
{
    public string Maker { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public double Location { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

En el `main` Llamo y creo el `List<>` de la siguiente forma:

```
        string archivoJ = File.ReadAllText("Cars.json"); //Cargamos el archivo.

        List<Cars> coches = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cars>>(archivoJ); //Creamos una lista con el json.
```

Y en mi método donde debo ejecutar la Query:

```
    static void Ejer4(List<Cars> lc)
    {
        var fm = lc.Where(x => x.Color == "Fuscia").Select( y => new { Fabricante = y.Maker, Modelo = y.Model });

        foreach(var i in fm)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Fabricante: {i.Fabricante} Modelo: {i.Modelo}");
        }
    }
```

Pero al ejecutar, me aparece la siguiente excepcion, marcando la posición del `JasonConvert`:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'. Path '[0].Year', line 1, position 63.'
```

En la clase `Cars` he probado a cambiar los tipos de datos a `string` todos, pero sigue en lo mismo. ¿Como puedo evitar que convierta los tipos `null`?

Comment: Tiienes un campo null en tu json y lo intenta castear

Comment: ¿Y como se puede solucionar? Estoy un poco verde aun con estos temas

Comment: mapea tu json y haz caso a @PaperBirdMaster

Comment: ¿Hacerme caso en qué? @NicolasOñate he explicado la duda, no he dado directrices de nada.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster He visto el futuro

Comment: @NicolasOñate te [creo](https://dle.rae.es/?w=creer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El error es claro y conciso, tal vez no lo entiendas por estar en inglés, lo traduzco:

> ```
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'. Path '[0].Year', line 1, position 63.'
> ```

> ```
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error convirtiendo el valor {null} a 'System.Int32'. Path '[0].Year', línea 1, posición 63.'
> ```

Tu JSON tiene una sola línea, la posición 63 es:

```
{"id":1,"Maker":"Mercedes-Benz","Model":"SL-Class","Year":null,"Color":null,"Location":{"Latitude":null,"Longitude":null}}
                                                             ><
```

El error es obvio: No se puede convertir el valor `null` (que está en la posición 63) a un número entero (que es lo que se supone que es un año).

---

> ¿Cómo puedo evitar que convierta los tipos `null`?

Puedes configurar el [deserializador de Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm) para que ignore los valores nulos, para ello debes crear un objeto de configuración:

```
var configuracion = new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
/* ignorar nulos */     NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                    };
```

Y facilitarlo al deserializador:

```
List<Cars> coches = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cars>>(archivoJ, configuracion);
```

Opcionalmente, podrías haber hecho que el año fuese [*nullable*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/):

```
class Cars
{
    public string Maker { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int? Year { get; set; }
//         ^^^^ <--- Year puede ser null
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public double Location { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Pero lo más adecuado es que sanees tus datos de entrada: Un año no puede ser nulo en este contexto.

Comment: ¿Y como puedo evitar que convierta el tipo `null`?

Comment: puedes hacerlo añadiendo `if (x == null){0}`

Comment: @Youshiro si tu duda es sobre cómo deserializar JSON edita la pregunta o abre una pregunta nueva.

Comment: Listo, editada.